# Trying to select the object from api call in django

Tags: python, html, json, django, api

I'm trying to make a call from an api and use the film's id to make a new call but the film's id is not the object's id.  All the ways I tried to get this information either gave me the same film id for all objects.  Any suggestions

apis.py - Here I call search_film() to get the list of movies and then I save that data to a json file.  I want to use that data to select the correct object to use the film's id in the get_film() function

```
import requests
import json


def search_film(movie):
    movies_list = []

    url = f"https://imdb-internet-movie-database-unofficial.p.rapidapi.com/search/{movie}"

    headers = {
        'x-rapidapi-host': "imdb-internet-movie-database-unofficial.p.rapidapi.com",
        'x-rapidapi-key': "bff6c04355msh46e32c3afb8d323p1eaeedjsnbf048a37783e"
        }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
    titles = response.json()


    with open('film_data.json', 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(titles, json_file, indent=4, sort_keys=True)


    for i in range(len(titles['titles'])):
        movies_list.append(titles['titles'][i])


    return movies_list

def get_film():
    film_list = []

    movie = ""

    url = f"https://imdb-internet-movie-database-unofficial.p.rapidapi.com/film/{movie}"

    headers = {
        'x-rapidapi-host': "imdb-internet-movie-database-unofficial.p.rapidapi.com",
        'x-rapidapi-key': "bff6c04355msh46e32c3afb8d323p1eaeedjsnbf048a37783e"
        }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
    movie  = response.json().beautiffy()
    return film_list
```

views.py - I tried to create a button function to get the ID but that didn't work as planned. The id repeats for all objects.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Film
from .forms import SearchForm
from .apis import search_film, get_film
import json
import requests


def button(request):
    django_list = []
    print("Hitting button function")

    with open('film_data.json', 'r') as content:
        data = json.load(content)
        for item in data['titles']:
            django_list.append(item['id'])

    return render(request,'film/search_film.html',{})

def view_name(request):

    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = SearchForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            # form.save()
            context = {
                "films":search_film(title)
            }
            print("Searching for films....")
            return render(request,'film/search_film.html',context)

    else:
        form = SearchForm() # An unbound form

    return render(request,'film/search_film.html',{'form':form})
```

Search_film.html - Here is the html for the view this works correctly but when I click on more details I get the same data.

```
    <section class="results">

          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <!-- Cards with Title and image -->
                      <ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal flex-wrap">
                          {% for film in films %}
                        <li class="list-group-item">
                          <div class="card-deck">
                          <div class="card border-0" style="width: 15rem;">
                              <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ film.image }}" alt="film image" style="width: 100%;height: 363px;object-fit: fill;">
                              <h5 class="card-title">{{ film.title }}</h5>
                              <h5 class="card-title">{{ film.id }}</h5>
                              <div class="d-flex align-items-end mybtn">
                                <button class="jsbtn" id="{{forloop.counter}}" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>                               
                               </div>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                        </li>
                          {% endfor %}
                      </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <script>

      function myFunction() {
        var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('mybtn');
        for(var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++){
          buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function(){ 
            console.log({{ film.id }})
            alert({{ films.id}})
         })
}
      }
      </script>
```

I also tried to make a call in javascript but that failed too as I wasn't getting the correct object.  From my understanding I should be able to do this without javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not mess the code and do not put obstacles and difficulties to yourself. Just make an `AJAX` request with **JavaScript** in your client. In **Django** this is your rendered template. I highly recommend you to use **jQuery**, it makes your life with `Promises` and `API` calls so much easy. You really have put a lot of code and time to implement this `API` call, but there is certainly, as you see, a much easier implementation. I recommend you to use **jQuery** & **JavaScript**, due to the fact that they are built to provide developer-friendly ways to make and solve things on the modern web. That includes of course `API` calls and fetches.

I hope this helps you, even if I do not give a direct solution with your code.

Comment: Without overthinking as I have been doing.  I will not use my api call in python but instead I will make a call using JQuery and Javascript?

Comment: Exactly! Of course, you can do it with Python, but `API` calls are to be made from a client. **JavaScript** is a popular client-side programming language, and nowadays it is also server-side with **Node.js**. You are more likely to build yourself an `API` with Python itself.

Comment: Okay great!  I will try it out and see if I can get the desired results. You explained it good enough that I don't need to see the code. thanks

Comment: Okay, if you liked my answer I would really appreciate it if you upvoted it too!

Comment: I really appreciate it for accepting and upcoming my answer. Thank you!